# How do you check each element is different in two lists recursively in Prolog?

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, comparison

If you had a definition of check_entries(X,Y)., does anyone know what would be the best way to check two lists recursively and to iterate through those lists and compare each element to see if they are different or not?  I know you would use the =\= operator in there somewhere but I'm not sure what else to do...

Please help, thanks.  Recursion is a weak point of mine :-(.

More specifically, what I want to know is how to check that two lists of numbers L1, L2 are all different at each index. I'd also like to know how to use =\= to check for the inequality.

Comment: 1. Not clear what you are asking. You need to explain better (clearer). 2. If you wrote an algorithm, even iterative, in pseudo code, it will be much easier to know what your plan for a solution is. Please edit your question!

Comment: Added more clarification.

Comment: have you tried reading a tutorial and your Prolog's documentation?

Comment: Yes otherwise I wouldn't ask the question :).

Comment: Well, in all honesty, your question strongly suggests you haven't.

Comment: Sometimes people can't learn well from just reading documentation, sometimes people need extra help :).  Daniel helped me out on it anyway, my answer has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion isn't necessary:

```
all_different(L1, L2) :- forall(member(X, L1), \+ memberchk(X, L2)).
```

**Edit**: Indeed, your question is actually to ensure that if you match the lists up one-by-one, they are different. So these two would be different: `[1,2,1]` and `[2,1,2]`.

I still wouldn't bother with recursion, though I guess you could:

```
all_different(L1, L2) :- maplist(=\=, L1, L2).
```

Comment: Just for clarity: this succeeds if the the two lists don't share any elements (the "union" is the empty set). Not sure if this is what OP is asking :) BTW, both lists must be ground for this to work as intended.

Comment: I don't think this is working correctly. It just returns "yes."  What I want to know is how to check that two lists of numbers L1, L2 are all different at each index. I'd also like to know how to use =\= to check for the inequality.

Comment: If you have a way of doing that without recursion but using the =/= operator then that's okay also. Thanks.

Comment: For numbers, you should be using `=:=`. Try to see what will happen with `1 =\= 1.0` (or maybe that's intentional?)

Comment: It returns "no" but I'm pretty sure that's intentional.

Comment: @Boris the OP asked for `=\=`.

Comment: @F1R3 since when are 1 and 1.0 two different numbers?